# Do you have to initialize a php array before using it?

Tags: php

I am specifically wondering about:

```
$thisArray = array (
    'bla' => array (
        '4', '5', '6'
    )
);
```

Could I have just done this instead:

```
$thisArray['bla'] = array('4', '5', '6');
```

I can see that it works, but is it consider right and good practice?

Comment: Even better would be $thisArray['bla'] = ['4', '5', '6'];

Comment: Why this shouldn't be a good practice? An array is pretty much like every other varible so feel free to use it ;-)

Comment: Imho initialize means you assign type to variable with zero/null/false value at first. What you do here is different syntax for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about "good practice". Both options are valid (and won't produce notices). In first case you're aware about array data and, thus, are able to declare it explicitly with `array()`

But in common situation you'll not be able to declare array such way - it may be dynamic - it may have different values, it may have different dimensions e t.c. So while both options are valid, second would be used in many common cases where array will hold some data, which content is controlled by application logic.

To say more - almost all sense in having array is - to hold dynamic data which is structured according to your application architecture & logic.

Answer (score -2):

```
    **if i am wrong plz make me correct.**

    In php you Don't want to initialization variables and array...its totally depends upon you what you do .....
But in some cases when the value array and variable equal to null...then


     **case:1-**  When you are not define a variable and you are using that variable in if condition then it will gives you error notice..to make clear from that notice you want to put "@" sign before that

    **example:-**

    <?php    
    if($a==5){//here you not initialized variable so it gives you notice...
    //code to run
    }
    ?>


    **case 2:-** If you playing with array and doing same like not initialized that the it will also gives you notice:-

    example:-

    <?php

    foreach($arr as $arr1){ // here $arr is also not initialized
    //code to run
    }

    ?>
    help:- To save your self from notice plz initialized them equal to null_for more info follow this...

    http://php.vrana.cz/variable-initialization-in-php.php
```